# get an id of a specific form within several form on the same page (jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem, and i don't know how to get an id of a specific form when in the same page there is several form. Each form has a different id :

**HTML :**

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" id="acheter1">
    <input type="hidden" class="idProd8" name="idProd8" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="10">                       
    <button type="submit" id="addToCart" name="addToCart">Add</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="page.php" id="acheter2">
    <input type="hidden" class="idProd8" name="idProd8" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="20">                       
    <button type="submit" id="addToCart" name="addToCart">Add</button>
</form>
```

And this is the ajax

**Jquery :**

```
$('[id^=acheter]').submit(function() {
var CurrenID = $(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page.php",
            data: $('#'+CurrenID).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                    Method();
                }            
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: `data: $(this).serialize(),`.....

Comment: You're missing a lot of quotes, and there's no need to get the ID of the element to look up the same element!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: thanks for all your answers. @TasosBitsios i would like to get the id of the form (#acheter1 or #acheter2) i submit. And then i can serialize the good id. Theses 2 forms are on the same HTML page.

Comment: Ah, serverside. Gotcha. Owen's answer would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot OwenMelbourne and @MohammadAdil ! Your answers helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[id^=acheter]').submit(function() {
    var data = $(this).serialize()+"&form_id="+$(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                    Method();
                }            
        });
        return false;
    });
```

That will add your ID to the form post data?

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
$('[id^=acheter]').submit(function() {
```

change to

```
$('#acheter').submit(function() {
```

Note that the **id** must be unique if you want to get more than one value from diferent tags use **name** or **class**.

to check the forms using the id just make a input button instead input submit, each one with a diferent variable to the jquery and submit .

example :

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" id="acheter1">
    <input type="hidden" class="idProd8" name="idProd8" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="10">                       
    <button type="button" id="addToCart1" name="addToCart" onclick="submitF('1')">Add</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="page.php" id="acheter2">
    <input type="hidden" class="idProd8" name="idProd8" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="20">                       
    <button type="button" id="addToCart2" name="addToCart" onclick="submitF('2')">Add</button>
</form>
```

Then use jquery/javascript to check what button was clicked

```
function submitF(var)
{
if (var == 1)
{
...
    /*do what you want knowing that the first form was clicked, 
submit form with jquery if you want*/
...
}
if (var == 2)
{
...
    /*do what you want knowing that the second form was clicked, 
submit form with jquery if you want*/
...
}

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i need to find the id of the submitted form. Because there is several form with the id begin with 'acheter'(#acheter1, #acheter2). And the selector $('#acheter) will not match. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It works, the only thing is that i have lot of forms :)!And your jquery/javascript part will be heavy to code... :) @MohammadAdil gaves me the perfect solution. Great job, anyway. Best regards,